# Slicing a string based on user input printing the characters on each line

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically, i need to get the user to input some type of string and then get the user to input a number and slice the string depending on the users number and print on a new line every time it sliced. I don't think that made since so here is an example

```
Welcome to the jungle.
5
Welco
me to
the
jungl
e.
```

I understand how to slice it but i dont understand how to get it to continue slicing until the full string is printed

```
y=input('enter a sentence ')
x=int(input('enter a number '))
z=0
while z==0:
 z==0
 print(y[0:x])
 print(y[x:]
```

Comment: you may get a good solution using `range()`'s 3rd step size argument!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input string as the loop control variable.  That is, keep looping while there is still something left in the input string.  Here's a suggestion:

```
y=input('enter a sentence ')
x=int(input('enter a number '))
while len(y):
 print(y[0:x])
 y=y[x:]
```

And here's an example run:

```
enter a sentence Welcome to the jungle!
enter a number 5
Welco
me to
 the 
jungl
e!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y=input('enter a sentence ')
x=int(input('enter a number '))
[y[i:i+int(x)] for i in range(0, len(y), int(x))]

enter a sentence Welcome to the jungle.
enter a number 5
['Welco', 'me to', ' the ', 'jungl', 'e.']
```

OR simply:

```
y=input('enter a sentence ')
x=int(input('enter a number '))
for i in range(0, len(y), int(x)):
    print(y[i:i+int(x)])
enter a sentence Welcome to the jungle.
enter a number 5
Welco
me to
 the 
jungl
e.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input('enter a sentence ')
number = int(input('enter a number '))

while True :

    if string == "" :

        break

    print(string[:number])

    string = string[number:]

print(string)
```

Maybe you can try that.